# Cloud Code function: try-catch did not catch ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Here is a Cloud Code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('testQuery', function(request, response) {
    response.success('Test String');
});
```

I call this function by Parse Android SDK:

```
try {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("testQuery", params, new FunctionCallback<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ArrayList<String> results, ParseException e) {
            Log.d("Test", "Done");
        }
    });
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.d("Test", "Exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

I understand that I am casting from String to ArrayList, which will cause ClassCastException. So I add a try-catch, but the app still crash. What is the reason that I can't catch the Exception? Thanks.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.honestly, PID: 23014
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at app.myapp.MyActivity$1.done(MyActivity.java:189)
    at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: Your try/catch does not catch the exception because it happens on a different thread.

Comment: Oh... What should I do?

Comment: This depends on what you want to achieve. I'd start with specifying correct arguments for the function so that the exception does not happen.

Comment: @yole Thanks for your help. The function returns an ArrayList if it works fine, but sometimes it returns a string if the server is down or something like "This application performed 22470 requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit.". Is there any way that I can deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: Declare your callback as `FunctionCallback<Object>` and check the type of the value you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` suggest the `callback` parameter is executed asynchronously. The `try catch` is entered, the `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` and `callback` stored, the `try catch` is exited, then at some point in time the `callback` function is executed.

One way to solve it is to accept a `String` and then convert it to array list:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("testQuery", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void done(String results, ParseException e) {
        try { 
            List<String> result = convertToList(results);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("Test", "Problem " + ex);
        }
        Log.d("Test", "Done");
    }
});
```

Comment: What should I do if I need to catch the Exception? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @miensol, thanks for your help. The function will return an ArrayList if it works fine, but sometimes it returns a string if the server is down or something like "This application performed 22470 requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit.". Is there any way that I can deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: @iForests please provide a full stacktrace when the class cast exception occurs.

Comment: @iForests it seems that the exception happens in `done` method of callback on the line of code that you've not included in the question.

Comment: MyActivity$1.done(MyActivity.java:189) is `public void done(ArrayList<String> results, ParseException e) {`